# AWS Cognito Logging

Tags: cordova, authentication, mobile, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for authentication for my cordova app. I am having issues finding logs for cognito:
-if someone tried to signup 
-if the email verification code was sent
-or any interaction that the user has done using the aws sdk to signup

As per the documentation, i have checked cloudTrail but there isnt enough info in there. It just has events.

Is there any way to get detailed cognito logs or not possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Cognito there are three different ways to check and track the logs

- For each user in cognito, a log is generated and is visible in manage user pool->General Setting->Users and attribute->Click one user and go to the bottom of the page. If that user has logged-in before, logs will show the device, browser, oS used by the client to login.
- There is an Analytics section which can be enabled.
- By using Cognito SDK, these logs can be accessed using code.